# How to determine time of power outage?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I had a power outage during the night (which I didn't notice) and restarted the PC in the morning.

How can I now find the exact time of the power outage?

Is there a kind of "lifeness timestamp" which is posted somewhere ?

Comment: Can we assume it was not on a UPS?  If the computer suddenly loses power, it doesn't record anything, it's just off.  So there is no entry anywhere to find for the event.  Ian McKay's suggestion is to look for the hole.  Other activities generate logs, so look for when there were no log entries generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though you won't get an exact, I would generally use the Event Viewer for this. Open the Event Viewer by searching for it in your Start Menu. Once there, your most helpful logs will likely be Windows Logs. Scroll back through each to see gaps in your events and that'll tell you when (approximately).

Comment: Don’t know why this was downvoted. Barring any third-party software that logs regularly, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: @DanielB It was not me, I cannot vote at all, since I have only 6 points.

Comment: Yes thank you. I looked into event viewer, and the closest I can get are messages from some "Security-SPP" which seems to be logging around every 2 hours in general.

Comment: @askolotl Another thought, if you have other devices on the same power circuit that did start up you can check it's uptime. Biggest candidate for that would be your home router/modem. Most will have a section with current uptime hidden away.

Comment: Oh I really found a log in my modem, but it logged only when it rebooted. Anyway, thanks a lot! I have a time window now. Basically I wanted to find out what the reason was. Only one circuit failed, so it was a source within my apartment.And I suspect that it might have been the PC itself, because yesterday I had some harddisk troubles. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you have an actual power outage or did your machine just crash? Troubles with your hard disk should not trip a breaker.

Comment: @Seth No, a power outage - a fuse was kicked out. So one circuit was broken. Meanwhile I know it was a outage by the energy company. (happens very very rarely here)